# Commits on my git branch that don't belong there

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a remote branch that has yet to be merged into the master branch. I was simply performed a `git config pull.rebase true` and then a `git pull origin <branch_name>`. Then I committed and pushed my changes to my remote branch. Now, my branch shows all of these previous commits from other users on other remote branches that have been merged with the master. Why are these there and can I remove them? Should I perhaps delete this branch and start over?

Thanks

Comment: `git pull origin <branch_name>` this is going to pull commits on origin/branch_name that you don't have in your branch.  "Now, my branch shows all of these previous commits from other users" isn't that what you were going for when you did `git pull`?  Or was it your expectation that `origin/branch_name` didn't have the commit history you ended up pulling?

Comment: I was getting the error "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart" and "You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them". And so I rebased and ran this command in order to remedy that error.

Comment: @erik258 ^^^^^^

Comment: If you were behind `origin/branch_name`, that implies there were commits on `origin/branch_name` that you didn't have locally.  And `git pull` would have pulled them in and applied locally.  That's a normal way to pull in contributions from other collaborators.  Working as intended.

Comment: "my branch shows all of these previous commits ..." What does that mean? A branch is a name for _one_ commit.